# Book about ergodic theory, group actions and number theory

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation, ergodic-theory

Does anyone know about an introductory book showing the intersection between ergodic theory, group actions and number theory? I have been looking for but it has been impossible to me.

Answer (score 5):

There's [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0857290207) by Einsiedler & Ward on ergodic theory with a view towards number theory.

Also there's an expository article on the [application](http://www.sbm.org.br/docs/ensaio_matematico/em_17-arbieto-matheus-moreira.pdf) of ergodic theory in analytic number theory.

Comment: The link to the expository article seems to be broken.

Answer (score 3):

I like the survey article "Interactions Between Ergodic Theory, Lie Groups, and. Number Theory" by Marina Ratner. Look it up in Google.